# Google Api unable to display Users information

Tags: php, api

I am working with "**SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE API**" that I have embedded in my web page. On clicking the link on the webpage user is redirected to google asking users permission to allow access of basic information by the application. However when user is redirected to main webpage it does not displays users information.

Here is the main **index.php** where the user lands

```
<?php
    require_once "app/init.php";

    $gc   = new Google_Client();
    $auth = new GoogleAuth($gc);

    if($auth->checkRedirectCode()){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }


?> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyTalaash</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(!$auth->isLoggedIn()):?>

    <a href="<?php echo $auth->getAuthUrl();?>"> Sign in with Google</a>

<?php else:?>

    <a href="signout.php">Sign Out</a>

<?php endif;?>
</body>
</html>
```

The code in GoogleAuth.php is as follows

```
<?php

class GoogleAuth{

    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Google_Client $gc = null){
        $this->client = $gc;

        if($this->client){
            $this->client->setClientId('SOME secret');
            $this->client->setClientSecret('SOME secret'); 
            $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/myTalaash/index.php');
            $this->client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
        }
    }

    public function isLoggedIn(){
        return isset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    public function getAuthUrl(){
        return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    public function checkRedirectCode(){
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
            $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $this->setToken($this->client->getAccessToken());

            //$payload is supposed to contain user information but it doesnt

            $payload = $this->getPayLoad();
            echo "<pre>".print_r($payload,true)."</pre>";

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function setToken($token){
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
        $this->client->setAccessToken($token); 
    }

    public function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    // The below function is responsible to get user information

    public function getPayLoad(){
        $payLoad = $this->client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
        return $payLoad;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line your **index.php** file..

```
if($auth->checkRedirectCode()){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

with this..

```
if($auth->checkRedirectCode()){
    echo '<pre>', print_r( $auth->user ), '</pre>';
}
```

and then change your GoogleAuth.php file.

```
class GoogleAuth { protected $client;public $user;

public function __construct(Google_Client $gc = null){
    $this->client = $gc;

    if($this->client){
        $this->client->setClientId('SOME secret');
        $this->client->setClientSecret('SOME secret'); 
        $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/myTalaash/index.php');
        $this->client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
    }
}

public function isLoggedIn(){
    return isset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

public function getAuthUrl(){
    return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
}

public function checkRedirectCode(){
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $this->setToken($this->client->getAccessToken());

        //$payload is supposed to contain user information but it doesnt

        $this->user = $this->getPayLoad();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function setToken($token){
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
    $this->client->setAccessToken($token); 
}

public function logout(){
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

// The below function is responsible to get user information

public function getPayLoad(){
    $payLoad = $this->client->verifyIdToken();
    return $payLoad;
}}
```